# Use minimal Angular in Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want to start a new Rails project which uses Angular.js for specific parts in the .html.erb files, but not everything. This especially means I don't want to use Ember's routing functionality but the one from Rails.

As an example, I want to render a dynamic list with e.g. sorting and search functionality using Angular. This means everything, except from creating the list and giving it it's functionality, everything is done in Rails. What’s be best way to do this in general?

Would it be a good idea to grab the data in a Rails controller, pass it to an Angular script in the bottom of the current page (not in a separate .js file), which then creates the list? (See the following example). Or should I rather place my javascript code in a seperate .js file? How could I then pass the data from the Rails controller to it?

Here is the example code. Is this a proper solution? Thanks a lot!

```
<html ng-app="todoApp">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="TodoController">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
          {{todo.title}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script>

    angular.module('todoApp', [])
  .controller('TodoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.todos = <%= @array_from_rails %> // <-- pass the data from Rails to Angular

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular apps generally like communicating with a server using JSON. It's a much better idea to leave your JavaScript code inside of a .js file. It shouldn't be dynamically generated - the asset pipeline should deliver JS code.

So you'll want to set up an API endpoint (e.g. `/todos`) in Rails that transmits the data you need in JSON format:

```
def index
  @todos = Todos.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @todos }
  end
end
```

You can then define an Angular module with a service (factory) to communicate with this endpoint:

```
angular.module('todoApp', [])
.factory('TodosService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('/todos');
});
```

And use this service in your controller to set the data on the scope as soon as it's available (see [documentation on $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)).

---

You'll then just need to use `ng-app="todoApp"` whenever you want to use the functionality you've defined in this module, without ever explicitly outputting generated JS code. It'll load up your module and run.

If you need multiple places of doing something like this, I'd recommend defining one global module and multiple controllers inside of it, as Angular will by default only run one `ng-app` directive, but is able to load up controllers at any point. You can then output HTML code that will "trigger" Angular whenever you need it.

Keep in mind that if you use Angular, you won't change pages while using the parts that run inside of it, so all communication (index/create/update/destroy) should run via JSON api endpoints.